# what is mean by " connection reset by peer"?

Tags: tcp, mqtt, telnet, netstat, peer

I am connecting multiple clients to single MQTT server Using MQTT Generic protocol. Suddenly at random time connection is getting disconnected and server goes into Disconnected status. This problem arises 2 to 3 times a week.

I have created one MQTT client and checked logs and found that connection is reset by peers.So created One flow to automatically restart server.

Comment: The "peer" is the other end of your connection. And "connection reset" means that the other end has sent a `RST` message to close the connection. So you need to look at what happened on the other side of your connection to understand what happened.

Comment: ... and one common reason that the MQTT broker closes the connection is on duplicate client ID.